# Access an EAR Deployed in one server from the EAR on another server

Tags: spring, jsf, servlets, ear

I have an application deployed in one Server and now i have created new application which i need to deploy in another server.Now I want to access functionality of first application to be visible from the menus of second application.

I am using Spring and Hibernate for new application and Old one is in JSF,Servlet,JSP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The functionality" is massively ambiguous: Is there a webservice/EJB/Managed bean method/destination page you want in the other EAR?

Comment: Destination page you can say.Lets say we have a landing page on first application and i click on menus of second application which has a kind of link to go to landing page of first application then it should let me to do that.its kind of switching from one application to another like using SSO.